# Hover issue with circle gradient effect

Tags: d3.js

I have modified this code: http://jsfiddle.net/LjsnD/  to include mouseover effects but there is some colour bleed in the clusters.  Is there a better way to achieve this instead of repeating the grad code? https://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/pten28uy/2/

```
var grads2 = svg.append("defs").selectAll("radialGradient2")
      .data(nodes)
     .enter()
      .append("radialGradient")
      .attr("gradientUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
      .attr("cx", 0)
      .attr("cy", 0)
      .attr("r", "100%")
      .attr("id", function (d, i) { return "grad2" + i; });

    grads2.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "0%")
        .style("stop-color", "white");

    grads2.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "100%")
        .style("stop-color", function (d) {
            console.log(d.cluster);

            return color2(d.cluster);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: IDs *have* to be unique.

In your code, you are duplicating some IDs. For you `grads`, you set the ID using this code:

```
grads.attr("id", function (d, i) { return "grad" + i; });
```

And, for your `grads2`, you used this:

```
grads2.attr("id", function (d, i) { return "grad2" + i; });
```

Now let's see: what happens if `i` is 21 to `grad` and `i` is 1 to `grad2`? You'll have two identical IDs:

```
grad + 21//gives you 'grad21'
grad2 + 1//gives you 'grad21'
```

The solution is simple: use letters instead:

```
grads.attr("id", function (d, i) { return "gradA" + i; });
grads2.attr("id", function (d, i) { return "gradB" + i; });
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/gs6eem6m/1/

Comment: Great spot.  I'd have sweated that one for ages!   Any ideas on a more elegant solution than repeating the grad code?  Others have done it using the css classed method but I couldn't apply it myself.

Comment: I normally don't work with gradients... maybe you can post another question regarding this with the tag `svg`, not `d3`, it can receive more attention.

Comment: @user3359706 Just a tip, not related to the question: when you accept an answer it gives you points, and make people more inclined to help you next time you post a question.